# Is my backup completed or not, when rsync command does not return and I have to type Ctrl + Break?

Tags: rsync, backup

I run the following command to backup my files:

```
duplicity --no-encryption  /home/digital        file:///media/tidy/backup/
```

The backup hangs and the command prompt does not return. So I enter `Ctrl+Break` and then I see the following output:

```
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
StartTime 1639158201.25 (Fri Dec 10 11:43:21 2021)
EndTime 1639194563.12 (Fri Dec 10 21:49:23 2021)
ElapsedTime 36361.87 (10 hours 6 minutes 1.87 seconds)
SourceFiles 548918
SourceFileSize 510742995764 (476 GB)
NewFiles 219688
NewFileSize 259947706258 (242 GB)
DeletedFiles 26498
ChangedFiles 44246
ChangedFileSize 158461815140 (148 GB)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 290432
RawDeltaSize 261041103997 (243 GB)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 256416093079 (239 GB)
Errors 0
-------------------------------------------------

Releasing lockfile b'/home/digital/.cache/duplicity/66a50d59cbce2c117894e763763417a9/lockfile'
Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-fm28xukk-tempdir/mkstemp-wr6uw4zk-1
INT intercepted...exiting.
Releasing lockfile b'/home/digital/.cache/duplicity/66a50d59cbce2c117894e763763417a9/lockfile'
Releasing lockfile b'/home/digital/.cache/duplicity/66a50d59cbce2c117894e763763417a9/lockfile'
```

Is my backup complete or not?

I have a `server1` and a `server2`. An external hard drive is attached to `server2`, which I use to backup the files that I have on `server1`. To do so, I share the external hard drive using `samba` at the address `//192.168.1.11/tidy-mine`. Then I mount this shared folder on `server1` using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o     username=tidy,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000  //192.168.1.11/tidy-mine  /media/tidy/
```

Comment: Why do you think your backup has hung? What was it writing to?

Comment: I added additional explanation regarding what rsync was writing to. I think rsync hung up, because rsync did not produce any output and the command prompt was not returned. When I typed `Ctrl+Break`, rsync produced an output on the terminal and also the command prompt was returned so I could type other commands on my terminal.

Comment: Is this an incremental (changed files only) or an initial full backup? If it's an incremental it's possible that `rsync` was skipping the files it didn't need to copy. Sometimes this produces no output

Comment: It was an incremental backup.